# Is the empire building tag constructive?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few months ago I created the [empire-building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empire-building) tag for my chain of medieval questions. So far, the only questions in this tag are [my 3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empire-building). Is this tag constructive to the site?

I created it and I think it is, but I want an opinion from someone (maybe a mod?). Does this fall into the category of "Not often used" or the "Not constructive, let's toss it" category?

Answer (score 7):

A general principle I go by is this: if *you* create a tag, *you* have to demonstrate that it has worth to the site, usually by adding a tag wiki.

In this case, you did add a tag wiki, which was approved. It is from this and a quick read-through of the questions that I base my opinion, which is this:

- We don't appear to have any other tags whose scope cross.
- It is a valid aspect of worldbuilding - empires are important to the politics and dynamics of a world.
- Therefore, I think this tag, although little-used, definitely has a place on this site.

(Side note: it may be little-used, but if people need a similar tag, the tag search box should bring it up.)